# My javascript function not showing response

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, responsive

I don't know why but my code is not working I want to make a responsive navbar

**HTML CODE**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
<i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" onclick="navigation()"></i>
<a href="#" class="logo">The Big Blog </a>
    <div id="navLis">
      

      <ul>


        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Get Started</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Popular Bloggers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact U</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navLis {
  display: none;
}

nav ul{
  margin-top: 20px;
   color: white;
  background: black;
}

nav{
  height:100px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  background: #8dc09b;
}

nav li  {
  display: inline-block;
 
  padding: 6px;
}

nav li a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav i {
  display: none!important;
  font-size: 2em!important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  transform: translate(-10px);
  
}

.logo{
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px!important;
}



@media (max-width:668px){
   
   nav {
     height: 60px;
   }
   
  
   
  nav li {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
  }
  
  nav i {
    display: block!important;
  }
}
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function navigation() {
  const navLis = document.getElementById('navLis');
  
  if (navLis.style.display = 'none') {
    navLis.style.display = 'block';
  }else{
    navLis.style.display = 'none';
  }
  
}
```

**My problem is that My div with id navLis has display none and I have written in JavaScript that when it is display none do display block  simple! Buy when I click on hamburger my navigation () is just making it visible but when I click again to hide my list it is not working**

Comment: For starters, you're assigning in an if condition.

Comment: Thanks  I realised the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a small type there:

```
function navigation() {
  const navLis = document.getElementById('navLis');
  
  if (navLis.style.display === 'none') {
    navLis.style.display = 'block';
  }else{
    navLis.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

this should work.

To check if navLis.style.display is 'none' you used =, instead of === you assigned is the value none there

Comment: Thanks bro  I realised it now I didn't look there